# SSRS can't find server on which SQL Server is installed

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I'm running **SQL Server 2012**, and I'm trying to configure **Reporting Services**. I've confirmed that the service is running on my system, but when I start up **Reporting Services Configuration Manager**, there is **no** server listed in the start up screen, where it asks to **Connect to a Server**. When I type in the name of the server, I get a pop up saying,

> `Cannot Find <Server Name>`

That's as far as I get, and I cannot understand why it would not automatically populate the server name or, even less clear, why it wouldn't be able to find the Server once I entered the name in manually.

I wish I could give more information but that's really as far as I get. Are there some basic configurations I can check to see why it's not "aware" of itself as a SQL server?

Answer (score 3):

In my case SSRS was installed but not correctly configured.

I had to use Reporting Services Configuration Manager to create a database (Database panel) and then enable the web services using the 'Web Service URL' panel.

Once both these steps had been completed, I was able to connect via SSMS.

Comment: _But_ the OP cannot connect via RSCM in order to create a database

Answer (score 0):

If there's no reporting service instance name displayed in Reporting Services Configuration Manager, it means the Reporting Services instance is not installed properly. You can try to re-add feature(SSRS) to existing SQL instance. Please troubleshooting the installation for SSRS.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144289(v=sql.110).aspx

Also make sure you start SSRS administration tool for right SQL instance.